# Filter nginx access log

Tags: linux, bash, http, nginx, logging

in NGINX access log (default log format), what commands would I use to filter the log for all GET requests and then uniquely sort all HTTP response status codes along with the total count of each status?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 2):

It may differ because of some log formating:

```
cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.1 | grep "GET" | awk '{print $9}' | sort | uniq -c
```